# Trying to validate that user didn't enter "0" error: cannot implicitly convert int to string

Tags: c#

I am including a screenshot, I am unsure how else to ensure the user didn't enter "0". The screenshot shows an example from my past hw, where this worked, but this time, i get the "cannot implicitly convert type int to string error"

OK so I can't post images yet, so here is my code:

```
 if (int.TryParse(textBoxDivisor.Text, out divisorInt))
        {
            //correct
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid divisor!");
            return;
        }

        if (textBoxDivisor.Text = 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by 0");
            return;
        }
        else
```

etc. The error is the line: if (textBoxDivisor.Text = 0) the "0" is underlined in red with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `==`  you are trying to assign while you need to check

```
 try
      {
    if (int.Parse(textBoxDivisor.Text) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by 0");
                return;
            }
        } 
    catch (FormatException)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to convert '{0}'.", textBoxDivisor.Text);
      }
```

Comment: yes, I am I have to wait 8 mins according to the site :) Thank you again!

Comment: What happen here if you type a string instead of a number?

Comment: he will get a format  exception  take a look now I think  it will be better to catch exception  here instead of using tryparse which  let the misstyped value  passed unobserved

Answer (score 3):

```
if (int.TryParse(textBoxDivisor.Text, out divisorInt))
        {
            if (divisorInt != 0)
            {
            //correct
            }
            else
            {
                 // blah blah blah
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid divisor!");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with in the if condition , it should be like:

```
if (textBoxDivisor.Text == "0")
```

Hope this helps.